# Razor Class Library image appears on the landing page but not on any other pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views, razor-class-library

**Overview:**

Hello, I have created a Razor Class Library that is being consumed as a NuGet package. I have the partial view referenced in the `_Layout.cshtml` of the client application and I am having an issue with an image loading reliably. All the relevant code is shown below. Both the library and the client are written using .NET Core 3.1.

**Problem Statement:**

When launching the application the image `myCompanyLogo.png` is loaded for the landing page. However, after navigating away from the landing page, the logo is not displayed. When I navigate back to the landing page, the logo is successfully displayed again.

**Code:**

In the library, the included image file `myCompanyLogo.png` is marked as "Content" and "Copy if newer". I have a component called `_Header.cshtml`. This component is defined as such:

```
@model HeaderViewModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Library.UserInterface/css/library.css" />

<header class="companyRed">
    <a class="navbar-brand m-2" href="https://example.com">
        <img src="_content/Library.UserInterface/images/myCompanyLogo.png"
             style="height:5em;width:auto">
    </a>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm text-light bg-light border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand text-dark"
               asp-controller="@Model.ApplicationHomePage.ControllerName"
               asp-action="@Model.ApplicationHomePage.ActionName">@Model.ApplicationName</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler"
                    type="button"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target=".navbar-collapse"
                    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    @foreach (var key in Model.MenuItems.Keys)
                    {
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark"
                               asp-controller="@Model.MenuItems[key].ControllerName"
                               asp-action="@Model.MenuItems[key].ActionName">@key</a>
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

This is being consumed within the client application in the `_Layout.cshtml` file as such:

```
<body>
    <partial name="_Header" 
             model='new HeaderViewModel
                    {
                        ApplicationName = "Event Management",
                        ApplicationHomePage = new HeaderViewModel.ControllerActionPair
                        {
                            ControllerName = "Event",
                            ActionName = "Index"
                        },
                        MenuItems = new Dictionary<string, HeaderViewModel.ControllerActionPair>
                        {
                            { 
                                "Events",  new HeaderViewModel.ControllerActionPair
                                {
                                    ControllerName = "Event",
                                    ActionName = "Index"
                                } 
                            }
                        }
                    }' />

    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

<!-- Footer, Scripts, etc. omitted -->

</body>
```

and for completeness, `HeaderViewModel.cs` is defined like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Library.UserInterface.ViewModels
{
    public class HeaderViewModel
    {
        public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
        public ControllerActionPair ApplicationHomePage { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, ControllerActionPair> MenuItems { get; set; }

        public class ControllerActionPair
        {
            public string ControllerName { get; set; }
            public string ActionName { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this work: `src="/_content/Library.UserInterface/images/myCompanyLogo.png"`? (adding a slash (`/`) in front of the link) Without the slash it searches for a relative link.

Comment: Yes, this fixed it! Thank you for the quick and accurate response, Poul Bak.